# Sorting C array depending on a condition

Tags: c

I have arrays which I'm trying to access them one by one and get the smallest number in the arrays based on the user input, the issue is I'm required to make a function for the getting lowestPrice.

I'll try to explain the code and I hope I can find a solution for it.

```
        A user would like to buy a car when he/she is given a list of car prices as
    an array of integers. The customer would like to be able to query the array and
    find the order of lowest price as he/she prefers, 
means if he want the samllest second elemnt in array then he must enter 2, if he wants the fifth samllest element in array then he must enter 5.
```

so if I want to write a function called : `lowestPrice(int prices[], int size, int order)`

And try to apply it for this example : `int testA1[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };`

How is that possible? I thought about using a switch case but I didn't figure it out :)

Comment: `qsort()` descending and access `array[input-1]`. (validating that `input-1` is a valid index for the array beforehand)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from the comment, the simplest way to get the nth lowest price within the values of the array is simply to sort the array (always use `qsort()`) and then just subtract `1` from the argument to convert the nth number to an array index and then output the requested index, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* qsort compare function */
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(int *)a > *(int *)b) - (*(int *)a < *(int *)b);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int testA1[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 
                   29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 },
      ndx = 0,
      nelem = sizeof testA1 / sizeof *testA1;
  
  if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1 argument given */
    fputs ("error: requires 1 argument\n"
           "usage: ./program n-lowest-price\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &ndx) != 1) {  /* convert to int */
    fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (ndx == 0 || ndx > nelem) {  /* validate ndx-1 good index */
    fputs ("error: index out-of-range.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  qsort (testA1, nelem, sizeof *testA1, compare); /* sort array */
  
  printf ("price: %d\n", testA1[ndx-1]);          /* output price */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getprice 2
price: 10000
```

(there are two `10000` values, the 2nd value in the array is `10000` as well)

Looking at the 3rd, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/getprice 3
price: 20000
```

Let me know if you have questions about the validations or the sort and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: I actually didn't understand it,

Comment: I'll try to expand a bit. Your array of integers after being sorted can be accesses with indexes `0 <= i < nelem`. When the user wants the nth price, all you need to do is subtract `1` from the `nth` value entered by the users. Why `n - 1`? We count `1 ... 10` but for an array (all indexing in C), the values start at `0`. So a 10-element array in C has valid indexes `0 <= i < 10` (or from `0 ... 9`). The `compare()` function parameters are *Pointers* to elements of the array. So `a` and `b` are type `int*` which you must dereference to get `int`. `*(int*)b - *(int*)a` can overflow.

Comment: So that is why the `compare()` function is written as the result of two conditional expressions. With `qsort()`, the `compare()` function returns `-1` if `a` sorts before `b`, `0` if they are equal, or `1` if `b` sorts before `a`. (any negative or positive number will also work). Take a couple of values for `a` and `b` and plug them into the `compare()` and see the result. It will become clear. All `compare()` functions are written to work with `qsort()` that way. So once you understand what the `compare()` function does, you can write one to sort anything you need to sort.